# Async python script from node js

Tags: javascript, python, asynchronous

I have a node.js program that runs around 50 different python script instances. I would like to be able to throttle the phase - such that at any one time, only 4 processes will run parallel.

I tried a simple loop that calls a function that runs 4 instances of the python script. I used 60 seconds delay as this is the average time takes the script to run.

```js
function startPythonScraping(){
  for(var i = 0; i < finalList.length; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        runFourProccesses(finalList[i]);
    }, i*60*1000);
   }
}


function runFourProccesses(stockSymbol){
    console.log("working on " + stockSymbol);
    for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        if(j == 0){
            trueOrFalse = "y"
        } else {
            trueOrFalse = "n"
        }
    let secondPythonProcess = spawn('python',     ["/Users/nybgwrn/Desktop/AlphaSecWebsite/getAllData.py",     stockSymbol, (j*10).toString(), "10", trueOrFalse]);
  secondPythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    let messegeFromPython = JSON.stringify(data.toString('utf8')).replace("\\n", "");
            console.log(messegeFromPython + " with stock " + stockSymbol);


            
            if(messegeFromPython != "something went wrong"){
                //console.log("created file for " + symbol);
            } else {
                //console.log("couldn't create file for " + symbol + "_" + (j*10).toString() + "-" + (j*10 + 10).toString());
            }
        });
    }  
}
```

It doesn't work because somehow the index i begin with 50 instead of 0, and also I want a better solution as I want to be SURE that only 4 instances are running.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually done using semaphores. A semaphore is basically a pool of locks, so that multiple locks can be held at the same time.

In your case you could use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semaphore) and wrap each python process spawning with `sem.take` and `sem.leave`.